# iOS - Resizing UIScrollView content at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a view that looks like the following:

[image: View screenshot]

The red rectangle (referencing outlet: self.redView) is put inside of a scrollview (referencing outlet: self.scrollView). When the "Bigger" or "Smaller" buttons are pressed, the red rectangle expands / contracts its height.

My code is here:

```
#import "s1cViewController.h"

@interface s1cViewController ()

@end

@implementation s1cViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 600)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnBiggerTouched:(id)sender {
    [self resizeViewHeight:20];
}

- (IBAction)btnSmallerTouched:(id)sender {
    [self resizeViewHeight:-20];
}

- (void)resizeViewHeight:(int)heightDelta {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        // Resize scrollview height
        /*self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height + deltaInputWrapperHeight);*/

        // Resize categoryInputView height
        CGRect rect = self.redView.frame;
        rect.size.height += heightDelta;
        self.redView.frame = rect;
    }];
}

@end
```

When I change the height of the rectangle, and then scroll, the height changes back to its original size. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are using auto layout. If so, that's the problem. You cannot change a view's frame directly under auto layout, because if you do, when layout comes along, it will just change it right back (as seems to be happening here). You have to change the constraints.

Comment: Is there a way to animate this?

Comment: Yes, of course. The easiest is just to animate the change in the constraints. See my full discussion of this topic here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout